# How would the existence of a magnetic monopole require the removal of world line from spacetime?

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity, quantum-electrodynamics

I was studying Lienard-Wiechert Potentials from Griffiths, where he wrote that electric charges cannot travel at the speed of light. Which led me to a rabbit hole of charges both magnetic and electric, wherein I stumbled upon the fact that the sheer existence of monopoles would require the removal of worldline from spacetime. Even after quite a bit of research, I couldn't understand what that meant and also how would they modify general relativity?

Comment: I'm not familiar with that statement - can you provide a source?

Comment: are you talking about Dirac strings? this is definitely not removing points from spacetime or modifying physics or anything, but is simply just a bad choice of coordinates. the issue is really just trying to use a single coordinate system (for the vector potential of the $B$ field) to describe the monopole. its the same thing as trying to use one coordinate system on the sphere, you end up with a singular point at a pole. use two vector potentials there's no issue

Comment: this is sometimes called the Wu-Yang monopole. there's a nice discussion of this in Nakahara's "Geometry, topology, and physics"

Comment: @Javier This was written on the wikipedia, while I know its not always accurate when it comes to since, still the statement intrigued me.
[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_monopole]

Comment: @4xion Here is what the page said 'The Dirac monopole is a singular solution of Maxwell's equation (because it requires removing the worldline from spacetime)'

Comment: @SobanBakhtiyar see my response above. this is just a coordinate singularity (where the $B$ field is not well-defined). nothing about spacetime or physics is changing, it's just a poor choice of coordinates. using two vector potentials, the $B$ field of the monopole is then non-singular